# Namespace issues in VS2017 and Win7 with Xamarin app?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017, windows-10, windows-7-x64

I have `VS2017 Community edition` installed in a `Windows 7` PC and a `Windows 10` laptop. They both have the exact same installation.

Last night I created a *Cross-Platform* > `Mobile App (Xamarin.Forms)` project in my Win10 laptop, and it ran perfectly in the android emulator. No issues there.

I did the same exact thing in my Windows 7 PC, and I'm getting tons of compiler errors. All of them are of the `The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found` nature.

Is there anything I need to do in Windows 7 so these projects run?

In both environments (Win7 and Win10) I did the exact same thing: installed VS2017, created the new Xamarin cross-platform project, and debugged it. In Win10 it runs flawlessly while in Windows 7 I  get a bunch of compiler errors with `System` namespace, which is literally the most fundamental namespace of the .NET Framework.

Any help is appreciated.

I'd like to add that I created a regular `ASP.NET Web Application` in Windows 7 and it runs flawlessly (no issues with `System` namespace), so it's an error with Xamarin cross-platform.

Comment: In their documentation they recommend using windows 10.

Comment: The Xamarin.Forms-based UWP project definitely will not compile/run on Windows 7.

Comment: UWP is not included as one of the projects.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for compiling the solution successfully on my Windows 7 PC was to install [.NET Framework 4.7.2](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/thank-you/net472)