# Is Xamarin.Forms supported in Windows 7? Wait for Windows 10?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, windows-7, visual-studio-2017

We have Windows 7 (x64) at work, and I wanted to learn about `Xamarin.Forms`. Specifically, I wanted to create a very basic app that will eventually run in an iphone and Android.

I installed VS2017 and tried running [Build your first Xamarin.Forms App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/get-started/first-app/?pivots=windows). Unfortunately, I've had tons of issues running this very basic app with the included emulator. I did not have any of these issues in my Windows 10 home PC.

My question is: Should I just let this go until my work PC is upgraded to Windows 10?

I ask because the learning curve for mobile app development is already pretty steep. It doesn't help that I'm running into compatibility issues because I have an unsupported OS.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/get-started/requirements#windows-requirements

Comment: Everything except uwp should work if i am right

Comment: make sure you have .net 4.7.2 SDK/target pack installed otherwise you get netstandard.dll issues.

Comment: I had already installed .net 4.7.2 SDK, which is why I was getting namespace errors: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54348149/namespace-issues-in-vs2017-and-win7-with-xamarin-app?noredirect=1#comment95512109_54348149

Comment: But installing the latest .net framework doesn't fix the issue I'm having with debug the app in the android emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin recommends using Windows 10, however

> The minimum operating system version is Windows 7. Xamarin.Forms UWP
>   support requires Windows 10.

[Official Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/get-started/requirements#windows-requirements)